# Validating an entity using a dynamic list of predicates

Tags: c#, performance, validation, extension-methods

I have a generic extension method for validating my entities. The main idea is to be able to specify at runtime (context related) the criteria for validating a specific entity (with the end goal of saving it in the data base).

```
public static Boolean IsValidEntity<T>(this T entity, List<Predicate<T>> predicates)
{
    Boolean res = true;
    predicates.ForEach(p => res &= (Boolean)p.DynamicInvoke(entity));
    return res;
}
```

Inside my repository I can then use (simplified as this is not the scope but is somewhat  necessary for the question context):

```
public void SaveIntProperty(int myProperty, List<Predicate<int>> predicates)
{
    if (myProperty.IsValidEntity<int>(predicates))
    {
        //save to data base or other actions
    }
}
```

A simple example on a list of `int`s would be to search for elements which (in a particular context) need to be both *even* and *less than 8*.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

//dynamically create the validation criteria
List<Predicate<int>> predicates = new List<Predicate<int>>();// List<Delegate>();
Predicate<int> lessThan = x => x < 8;
predicates.Add(lessThan);
Predicate<int> even = x => x % 2 == 0;
predicates.Add(even); 

numbers.ForEach(n => SaveIntProperty(n, predicates));
```

The `IsValidEntity` extension method works and looks simple enough. However, I'm having doubts about the performance and the extensibility. Is the use of the `ForEach` ok? Should I pass the predicates differently? Should I use something else instead of predicates?

Comment: There is no reason to use `List.ForEach()`, just use a normal `foreach`, it's actually even few characters shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify your extension method a bit as so:

```
public static Boolean IsValidEntity<T>(this T entity, IEnumerable<Predicate<T>> predicates)
{
    return predicates.All(p => (bool)p.DynamicInvoke(entity));
}
```

This is a bit better for readability, and shouldn't have any cost in efficiency as LINQ short-circuits with All. I also switched your `List` for `IEnumerable`, just to save an unnecessary `ToList` call if you end up with some other kind of collection.

You should also check if you really need that `DynamicInvoke`. If not, you can further simplify to

```
public static Boolean IsValidEntity<T>(this T entity, IEnumerable<Predicate<T>> predicates)
{
    return predicates.All(p => p(entity));
}
```

Depending on your wider design, this might be enough. However, since you asked about extensibility, you can see that having to build predicates isn't the nicest business. For example, you had your 'less than 8' predicate. What if elsewhere in the code you wanted 'less than 7'? You'd have to repeat the (albeit very simple in this example) logic, just with a different number.

If you tried to refactor this to adhere to the Don't Repeat Yourself principle, you might then end up with something like a `PredicateFactory` class which exists purely to build common predicates based on parameters. But this isn't fantastic design either. It would likely end up as a monolith of public methods without much cohesion, and violate the open/closed and single responsibility principle.

A better option might be to create an interface like:

```
interface IEntityValidator<T>
{
    bool IsValid(T Entity);
}
```

Instead of predicates, you can now create and use classes which implement this interface. This gives better adherence to the design principles I mentioned before, and allows you take full advantage of polymorphism (for more complicated validation you might find that inheritance is useful, for example). At this point your original method would be:

```
public static Boolean IsValidEntity<T>(this T entity, IEnumerable<IEntityValidator<T>> validators)
{
    return validators.All(v => v.IsValid(entity));
}
```

To my mind, that line is simple and readable enough that it may no longer warrant its own method, especially its own extension method which will apply to every single type. Validation doesn't seem like something that would be done in too many places, so even if you didn't like that line, you might just move it to a private method somewhere. That's more a matter of taste, though.

Comment: I don't see how does the interface help anything. I think that pretty much everything you can do with a single method interface, you can also do with a delegate. For example, you can still have each validator in a separate class, you would just use `MyValidator.Validate` (or `new MyValidator().Validate`) instead of `new MyValidator()`.

Comment: @svick I don't think there's anything you absolutely couldn't do with a delegate instead of an interface, especially since any class could just return a delegate which references private members. But at that point it just seems like a weirder way of doing the same thing. Why have a class that returns a function as a  delegate rather than just have that function be a public member? I didn't really understand what you meant with that example though, so I could be missing your point

Comment: I don't mean a method returning a delegate, I mean using that method as a delegate. Where you would have a class that implements `IEntityValidator<T>`, I would have a (possibly static) method and use that method as the `Predicate`. E.g. `Predicate<int> validator = new MyValidator().Validate;` (where `Validate()` is the validation method) instead of `IEntityValidator<int> validator = new MyValidator();`.

Comment: @svick Oh, right. Well I don't know Andrei's overall design, but having an interface means you don't have to hard-code dependencies. Adhering to the Dependency Inversion Principle means you can inject them, mock them in a test, use an IoC container, whatever. It's not always something that's important, but given what a lightweight thing the interface is and how little I know of the wider project design, it seems like a sensible thing to suggest by default. As a personal preference, I'd also find an interface like that very expressive in terms of readability

Comment: @BenAaronson, I don't have a highly complex design. I want to have as much "freedom" in my DAL as possible. I'm thinking that, for different clients, I need to have different business rules for specific entity types. It would then make sense that I can specify the validation rules from outside the DAL, with as little effort as possible.

Comment: @AndreiV I'd say the IEntityValidator is appropriate then.