# Search query utilizing menus and checkboxes

Tags: c#

I'm dealing with a searching query where the user will pick from menus and checkboxes the variables-criteria I'm passing to the `toWeb` method and a list will be returned. This works fine but I'm going to add two more variables and it's already hard to follow.

```
 public List<newEvent> toWeb(string name, string egk, string             
 typosSumvan, Boolean olaTaSumvanta)
 {
    List<newEvent> listaSumvantwn = new List<newEvent>();

    if (olaTaSumvanta == false)
    {
        if (egk != "")
        {
            if (typosSumvan != "")
            {
                using (var db = new CMMSEntity())
                {
                    foreach (var a in db.sumvanta)
                    {
                        if (a.apodektis == name && a.egkatastasi == egk && a.eidosSumvan == typosSumvan)
                        {
                            listaSumvantwn.Add(readFromTable(a));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (var db = new CMMSEntity())
                {
                    foreach (var a in db.sumvanta)
                    {
                        if (a.apodektis == name && a.egkatastasi == egk)
                        {
                            listaSumvantwn.Add(readFromTable(a));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (typosSumvan != "")
            {
                using (var db = new CMMSEntity())
                {
                    foreach (var a in db.sumvanta)
                    {
                        if (a.apodektis == name && a.eidosSumvan == typosSumvan)
                        {
                            listaSumvantwn.Add(readFromTable(a));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (var db = new CMMSEntity())
                {
                    foreach (var a in db.sumvanta)
                    {
                        if (a.apodektis == name)
                        {
                            listaSumvantwn.Add(readFromTable(a));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (egk != "")
        {
            if (typosSumvan != "")
            {

                using (var db = new CMMSEntity())
                {
                    foreach (var a in db.sumvanta)
                    {
                        if (a.egkatastasi == egk && a.eidosSumvan == typosSumvan)
                        {
                            listaSumvantwn.Add(readFromTable(a));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {//anazitisi xwris tupo
                //anazitisi xwris tupo sumvan
                using (var db = new CMMSEntity())
                {
                    foreach (var a in db.sumvanta)
                    {
                        if (a.egkatastasi == egk)
                        {
                            listaSumvantwn.Add(readFromTable(a));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {                        
            if (typosSumvan != "")
            {
                using (var db = new CMMSEntity())
                {
                    foreach (var a in db.sumvanta)
                    {
                        if (a.eidosSumvan == typosSumvan)
                        {
                            listaSumvantwn.Add(readFromTable(a));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {

                using (var db = new CMMSEntity())
                {
                    foreach (var a in db.sumvanta)
                    {
                        listaSumvantwn.Add(readFromTable(a));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return listaSumvantwn;
}
```

Comment: What type are the items of `db.sumvanta` ?

Comment: db.sumvanta is an sql table will strings and datetime cells mostly.

Comment: so `var a in  db.sumvanta` refers to a `DataRow` ?

Comment: exactly a holds the name of the cells and i'm passing them on an object, but that's for another post!

Comment: Please do not edit "thanks" into a post. Just upvotes will do.

Comment: Oh ok just wanted to justify why I picked that question and not the others.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Emmm... can't you just join your `bool` conditions? Or am I missing something?

```
//method names and class names should start with capital letter
public List<NewEvent> ToWeb(string name, string egk, string typosSumvan, Boolean olaTaSumvanta)
{
    List<NewEvent> listaSumvantwn = new List<NewEvent>();

    using (var db = new CMMSEntity())
    {
        foreach (var a in db.sumvanta)
        {
            if (!olaTaSumvanta && a.apodektis != name) continue;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(egk) && a.egkatastasi != egk) continue;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(typosSumvan) && a.eidosSumvan != typosSumvan)) continue;

            listaSumvantwn.Add(ReadFromTable(a));
        }
    }

    return listaSumvantwn;
}
```

Or using `LINQ`

```
public List<NewEvent> ToWeb(string name, string egk, string typosSumvan, Boolean olaTaSumvanta)
{
    using (var db = new CMMSEntity())
    {
        return db.sumvanta.Where(a => olaTaSumvanta || a.apodektis == name)
                          .Where(a => String.IsNullOrEmpty(egk) || a.egkatastasi == egk)
                          .Where(a => String.IsNullOrEmpty(typosSumvan) || a.eidosSumvan == typosSumvan)
                          .Select(a => ReadFromTable(a))
                          .ToList();
    }
}
```

Also you should consider using English language for naming purposes.

Comment: Almost everything is fine but the lengthy condition inside the `if` is a no-go ;-]

Comment: Not as lengthy, as original `if` chain though ^^

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I saw you updated and added the `continue` keyword. Why is that? It works without it.

Comment: Personal preference. Feel free to use the version you like, they do exactly the same thing. :)

Answer (score 16):

Each of your parameters is either adding a filter, or an ignored value.
We can construct a list of [Predicates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx), each one corresponding to a single parameter.

```
 public List<newEvent> toWeb(string name, string egk, string             
 typosSumvan, Boolean olaTaSumvanta)
 {
    var predicates = new List<Predicate<DataRow>>();
    if (!olaTaSumvanta) { predicates.Add(row => row.apodektis == name) }
    if (egk != "") { predicates.Add(row => row.egkatastasi == egk) }
    if (typosSumvan != "") { predicates.Add(row => row.eidosSumvan == typosSumvan) }

    using (var db = new CMMSEntity())
    {
        foreach (var a in db.sumvanta)
        {
            if (a.IsValidEntity(predicates))
            {
                listaSumvantwn.Add(readFromTable(a));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using an extension method taken from [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/44243), we then apply all the filters.

```
public static Boolean IsValidEntity<T>(this T entity, IEnumerable<Predicate<T>> predicates)
{
    return predicates.All(p => p(entity));
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Take a step back and look at the structure of the code and look for a repeating pattern. If you do that, you will see that following:

```
using (var db = new CMMSEntity())
{
    foreach (var a in db.sumvanta)
    {
        if (SOME BOOLEAN EXPRESSION INVOLVING a)
        {
            listaSumvantwn.Add(readFromTable(a));
        }
    }
}
```

Extracting this into a sub function will greatly improve this code.

```
private void SomeGoodFunctionName(Func<TYPE OF a, bool> shouldAdd)
{
    using (var db = new CMMSEntity())
    {
        foreach (var a in db.sumvanta)
        {
            if (shouldAdd(a))
            {
                listaSumvantwn.Add(readFromTable(a));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is then used like the following to never be nested more than 3 levels.

```
if (olaTaSumvanta == false)
{
    if (egk != "")
    {
        if (typosSumvan != "")
        {
            SomeGoodFunctionName(a => a.apodektis == name && a.egkatastasi == egk && a.eidosSumvan == typosSumvan);
        }
```

Since the boolean expressions are some what complicated, it would be better to create stand alone functions with names describing what is being checked. Then use that instead of a long lambda expression.

Note: In the last repeated block, there is no if block inside the foreach loop. This is equivalent to the boolean expression being `true`.

Answer (score 10):

*Let's assume the elements of the `db.sumvanta` are of type `Record`.*
You could move creation of the resulting `List` to the method:

```
public static List<newEvent> GetRecords(Func<Record, bool> match)
{
    List<newEvent> listaSumvantwn = new List<newEvent>();
    using (var db = new CMMSEntity())
    {
        foreach (var a in db.sumvanta)
        {
            if (match(a))
            {
                listaSumvantwn.Add(readFromTable(a));
            }
        }
    }
    return listaSumvantwn;
}
```

Then your method turns into the following:

```
public List<newEvent> toWeb(string name, string egk, string typosSumvan, Boolean olaTaSumvanta)
{
    if (!olaTaSumvanta)
    {
        if (egk != "")
        {
            return typosSumvan != ""
                ? GetRecords(a => a.apodektis == name && a.egkatastasi == egk && a.eidosSumvan == typosSumvan)
                : GetRecords(a => a.apodektis == name && a.egkatastasi == egk);
        }
        return typosSumvan != ""
            ? GetRecords(a => a.apodektis == name && a.eidosSumvan == typosSumvan)
            : GetRecords(a => a.apodektis == name);
    }

    if (egk != "")
    {
        return typosSumvan != ""
            ? GetRecords(a => a.egkatastasi == egk && a.eidosSumvan == typosSumvan)
            : GetRecords(a => a.egkatastasi == egk);
    }
    return typosSumvan != ""
        ? GetRecords(a => a.eidosSumvan == typosSumvan)
        : GetRecords(a => true);
}
```